# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenRequest on Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have built application on Spring Framework, build it with maven, package it as an EAR and deploy it to Weblogic 11g, and everything works fine.

However, when I try to deploy the same package to Weblogic 12c, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenRequest
```

Why does the Weblogic version upgrade introduces the dependency to this class? The dependency isn't even packaged in the EAR.

I think it has something to do with this dependency, which is used for token based authentication

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What is the problem, and what is generally the best workflow to diagnose these sort of problems systematically?

Comment: I think package `spring-security-oauth2` is missing.

Comment: So it is actually weblogic version thing. can thare possibly be some conflicting jar in 12c?  Or perhaps some missing? Still attaching pom might help to solve this.